# PHP: How to extend a 3rd party vendor class downloaded with composer and load it instead of the original?

Tags: php, composer-php

I have a library downloaded with Composer which performs several basic stuff but which has very poor class methods in some cases.
So I though to create my own class (for certain objects, not all of them) which extend the library base class and add some useful method to it.

Unfortunately I'm not very familiar with Composer and `autoloader.php`.

How can I achieve that? I need to create my own library and run composer?

Answer (score 0):

Two choices come to my mind, you can:

- Fork the entire project and change as many things as you want
- Extend the classes you need, and replace declarations/injections in your src code, there's no need to modify the autoloader.